# Output of colored point clouds

Tags: ros, rviz, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I think that it is pretty rudimentary, but I will ask you a question because I can not solve it by trial and error.
I am writing a program that outputs colored point clouds. So, I wrote the program as below, but on rviz a white point clouds is output. I changed the rgb value to various values, but there was no change. What should I do? Thank you.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> PointCloud;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init (argc, argv, "pub_pcl");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<PointCloud> ("points2", 1);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
    while (nh.ok())
    {
        PointCloud::Ptr msg (new PointCloud);
        msg->header.frame_id = "/my_frame";
        pcl_conversions::toPCL(ros::Time::now(), msg->header.stamp);
        msg->height = 480;
        msg->width = 640;
        msg->points.resize(480*640);


        for(int n=0; n<480; ++n) {
            for(int m=0; m<640; ++m) {
                msg->points[n*480+m].x = 1.0;
                msg->points[n*480+m].y = 0.01*(m-320);
                msg->points[n*480+m].z = 0.01*n;
                msg->points[n*480+m].r = 200;
                msg->points[n*480+m].g = 0;
                msg->points[n*480+m].b = 0;
                msg->points.push_back (msg->points[n*480+m]);
            }
        }

        pcl_conversions::toPCL(ros::Time::now(), msg->header.stamp);
        pub.publish (msg);
        ros::spinOnce ();
        loop_rate.sleep ();
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268554/output-of-colored-point-clouds/) by [Akitoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31363/akitoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-08-11**:
`msg->points.push_back (msg->points[n*480+m]);` is duplicating every point, you should leave it out.

**Comment by [Akitoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31363/akitoshi/) on 2017-08-12**:
Thank @lucasw. As you say, I have duplicated every points. However, erasing this one line did not solve the problem.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-08-13**:
I tried running the code and it comes out red, though I changed the index to `n*640+m`, it's not going to make it through the whole point cloud otherwise (479 * 480 + 639 << 480 * 640).  I'm using kinetic on 16.04.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-08-13**:
Maybe on earlier versions of rviz the uninitialized points screw up all color rendering?

**Comment by [Akitoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31363/akitoshi/) on 2017-08-14**:
I'm using indigo on 14.04. Today, once again I tried running the same code, somehow the display on the left of the rviz screen changed and it comes out red.  Was something amended in rviz's program? Anyway, I was able to solve it. I appreciate your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Akitoshi

I am not sure that you can assign the values directly like that. Refer to the pcl::PointXYZRGB documentation:
http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html

It says "Due to historical reasons (PCL was first developed as a ROS package), the RGB information is packed into an integer and casted to a float. " and there is an example of how to pack/unpack the rgb data.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Next to that you have to also make sure that the RViz pointcloud2 display is configured to show RGB values of points, instead of one of the other options.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-02-14**:
True, RGB should be set in the Color Transformer in Rviz pointcloud2.
Btw, I tried it out yesterday and managed to assign the colors without doing the packing/unpacking. The assignment worked directly: 
pcl::PointXYZRGB point; 
point.r = 255; 
...